# Swapping Tokens On BSC Testnet

Tags: solidity, remix, ether, binance

I'm having problems swapping two tokens on BSC Testnet, now i'm aware this code will probably work on mainnet, but i'm trying to get it to work on testnet first, It might seem trivial but I would appreciate if someone could assist

```
 address private constant WN = 0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd;

 function swap(uint _amountIn, address to_) external {
    // generate the uniswap pair path of token -> weth
    _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), _amountIn);
   
    transferFrom(0x5dbe1daA8A1CFE11b2F5330E39D3F466DB592bC5, address(this), _amountIn);
   
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = WN; 
    path[1] = address(this);

    uint onePercent = _amountIn.div(100).mul(2);
    uint tenPercent = _amountIn.div(10);
    
    uint _slippage = _amountIn.add(onePercent.add(tenPercent));

    // make the swap
    uniswapV2Router.swapTokensForExactTokens(
        _amountIn,
        _slippage, // accept any amount of ETH
        path,
        to_,
        now + 60
    );
}


function getAmountOutMin(uint _amountIn) external view returns (uint) {
  //path is an array of addresses.
  //this path array will have 3 addresses [tokenIn, WETH, tokenOut]
  //the if statement below takes into account if token in or token out is WETH.  then the path is only 2 addresses
  address[] memory path = new address[](2);
  path[0] = address(this);
  path[1] = WN; 
 
  uint[] memory amountOutMins = uniswapV2Router.getAmountsOut(_amountIn, path);
  return amountOutMins[path.length -1];
}
```

I keep getting the error

```
call to MelaCoin.getAmountOutMin errored: Error: Internal JSON-RPC error.
{
  "code": 3,
  "message": "execution reverted: PancakeLibrary: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY",
  "data": "0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002650616e63616b654c6962726172793a20494e53554646494349454e545f4c49515549444954590000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

I've approved the contract, and the wallet I want to spend has enough WBNB, is it failing because i'm the owner and im attempting to swap between my own wallets?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you, since solidity doesnt like decimals. when calculating percentages you must always multiply and then divide, also onePercent calculates 2 percent not one percent, so change the 2 to 1

```
uint onePercent = _amountIn.mul(1).div(100)
```

also thats not how you calculate slippage
in the case of swapping exact tokens for tokens
slippage is multiplying amountOut with (100-(your slippage))%

in that case of swapping for exact tokens, you multiply the amount in
with (100 + (your slippage))%

now since youre using getAmountsOut , you wanna swap a known number of tokens to a changing number of tokens based on slippage
then in the swap method you should use
swapExactTokensForTokens.

```
    uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForTokens(
    _amountIn,
    _amountOutMin, // Get that from the method GetAmountsOutMin
    path,
    to_,
    now + 60
);
```

}

now we are in case one which is swapping exact for non exact which you can calculate slippage by , slippage is multiplying amount out with (100-(your slippage))%
so you want 11% slippage
the code for slippage is

```
_amountOut = getAmountOutMin(_amountIn)
_AmountOutMin = _amountOut.mul(89).div(100) //this is the second paramater in the swap function
```

and finally unlike uniswap which uses the same address on both testnet and mainnet , pancakeswap router uses 0xD99D1c33F9fC3444f8101754aBC46c52416550D1 for testnet

Comment: Yes I'm using that router already, since the error is probably caused by the way im calculating slippage I will make some adjustments

Comment: But the error also occurs on getamountsOut as well...

Comment: The error says , insufficient liquidity are you sure address(this) or your contract has liquidity added on pancakeswap?

Comment: That must be the problem, a shame I didn't realise that earlier, I'll come back once I add liquidity to the token

Comment: Its probably the case, but even so ur code woulent have worked properly as well because of slippage miscalculation